# Signals and Systems: applying time shift operator on a system in \$\Psi \{x\}(t)\$ notation

Tags: signal, system

I didn’t quite understand how to apply a time shift operator on a system when checking time invariance.

For instance, if we have the system:

$$\Psi \{x\}(t)=(x(t))^{t}$$

and I want to shift it \$\tau\$ units forward; would we get this:

$$\sigma^{\tau} \Psi \{x\}(t) = (x(t +\tau))^{t + \tau}$$

or does the time shifted expression equal:

$$(x(t))^{t + \tau}$$?

Is there any intuitive explanation for this? I guess what I’m asking in a way is whether the system’s time changes the signal’s time.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think the solution is: $$\sigma^{\tau}\Psi\{x\}=\sigma^{\tau}y(t)= y(t+\tau) $$ $$
y(k)=(x(k))^k \implies y(t+\tau )=x(t+\tau)^{t+\tau}$$

Comment: now I don’t know if that’s true, but this is what I believe after going to a class where this notation was the topic

Comment: Shifting time means altering the t argument in its every occurence. So, yes, it's x(t+x)^(t+x) but, the fact that you, yourself, are not sure even after answering your question, it means that you really need to read some more, instead of posting blindly that which you do not understand. Put it this way: fast forward in time (since we're talking about time-shifting) and you'll need to solve, in real life, a case where you have to determine whether a system is LTI or not -- would you be able to do it, or would you flip a coin?

Comment: Also, if in the OP it was you then why not use your already-made account?

Comment: I used a phone. I haven’t had the account logged on and didn’t want to recreate the password. As for your question - I’d be able to. this wasn’t a blind post - I’ve read it and reread my course material and came up with two conflicting approaches which I couldn’t really choose between so I came here. The solution I posted came after a TA tutorial that really helped me hone in on the one.